# How to boot Ubuntu alongside Windows 8.1, not modifing Windows bootloader?

Tags: windows-8, uefi, ssd, system-installation

I know there's a few questions have been asked similar to this one, but I didn't find what I wanted.

I want to install Ubuntu 13 (13.10?) alongside Windows 8.1. The thing is Ubuntu doesn't recognize Windows. I want to install Ubuntu on SSD (Windows is on HDD, hdd is primary) and be able to run Ubuntu when I need (I don't wanna choose everytime on startup). As far as I know Ubuntu will try to write boot file to the primary disk (hdd in my case), and I'm afraid it will rewrite boot files from Windows.

So will it rewrite or not? Should be I afraid of something else?

Comment: Did you find a solution or read http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported